# Alternatives to serve with a tomato salad

Tags: substitutions, salad, serving-suggestion, chorizo

This weekend we are making a [Tomato and Chorizo salad](http://paganum.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/jamie-olivers-tomato-and-chorizo-salad/). The recipie suggests serving it with goats cheese and ham, but we don't really fancy that. We are trying to think of alternatives to serve it with and we just can't think past Mozzerella. Does anyone have any good ideas of what we can serve with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

halloumi or feta for cheese substitutes, especially if you can get the mint halloumi cheese.

as for ham substitute, I'd recommend toasted pita (served on top of the salad where you let the eater crush the bread themselves) or smoked salmon

Comment: +1 halloumi would be great here.  Slice it up and fry (or grill) it and fall in love with the cheesy squeak.  Not sure about the smoked salmon myself, but...

Comment: @Sam Holder - with the smoked salmon i was thinking a max of 1 or 2 super duper thin slices of smoked salmon put on top of the salad. Can be eaten with or without the salad. My goal with recommending the salmon was to include meat protein

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it'd be nice served on some crushed potatoes (Anya would be my choice, as they taste great and I have loads from the allotment, but any new waxy style would be good).

Just boil 'em till they're just done, squash each one with the back of a fork once, put on the plate and spoon the salad on top.  The potatoes will soak up the juices and make the salad a bit more substantial.

you could also try warming a small soft cheese (like [this](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/content/knowhow/glossary/vacherin/), or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pont-l%27%C3%89v%C3%AAque_%28cheese%29)) in the oven (maybe rub it in garlic first?) until its all gooey and slap that down in the middle of the salad, then eat the whole thing with some crusty french bread, no cutlery allowed, with maybe a little saucer of balsamic vinegar on the side to dip the bready gatherings in.

Comment: This sounds distinctly English.

Comment: the recipe suggestion or the language used to suggest it?

Comment: The recipe. My US brain would never connect a salad to potatoes. BTW I didn't mean anything negative by it.

Comment: haha, no problem, nothing negative inferred.  Strange I imagined potato salad to be an American thing.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [crushed potato idea](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/alternatives-to-serve-with-a-tomato-salad/3419#3419). Other possibilities:

- cubes of blue cheese (eg gorgonzola)
- grilled chicken breasts
- fresh steamed asparagus / peas / green beans
- leafy green salad (rocket, spinach, maybe add some pine nuts)
- roasted / grilled portobello mushrooms
- bruschetta or pitta bread

Now that I think about it, even a rice, pasta or cous cous base would go nicely with this, too.

This is making me hungry!!

Answer (score 0):

I make a tomato salad with blue cheese and candied pecans. The sweetness of the pecans might go well with the spiciness of the chorizo.